# Double backslash in cmd directory handling

Tags: batch-file, cmd, backslash

Due to sometimes empty variables within a cmd-script I get directory definitions with doubled backslashes (\\). Example:

```
SET "Mp3OutDir=%Mp3Root%\%AlbumDir%\%AlbumArtist1stChar%\%AlbumArtistSort_VDN%\[%Year%] %Album_VDN%"
```

leads, if %AlbumDir% is not defined by user within the procedure, to something like

```
mkdir "D:\Public\Music\Mp3CDRips\\G\Gabriel, Peter"
```

This seems to work without errors but I'm curious if a term like this is permitted by the cmd-interpreter.

Cheers, Martin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cmd interpreter seems to ignore extra back slashes in directory names. For example:

```
C:\>cd Windows\\\\\\\\\\\System32
```

This will still change the directory to `C:\Windows\System32>`.

So to answer your question, yes, a term like that is permitted by the cmd interpreter. As to why, I'm not sure.

Comment: It would be nice if anyone could point to some docs confirming this (it could be an implementation detail that only works in specific Windows versions).

Comment: I would guess Windows treats such path as C:\>cd Windows\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\System32 which does in fact resolve to C:\Windows\System32

Comment: I think this is due to a common error when composing paths: for example set foo=C:\Folder\  then referencing foo as copy %foo%\file.txt c:\temp. If the command interpreter didn't collapse slashes, this would cause an error, but it's very common.